# Tests for redis wrapper

Tags: unit-testing, go

I've written a wrapper package for redis. The idea is to be able to provide better error reporting with the package, as well as integrating stats and logging at a later stage. For now it's just better error reporting with traces.

My first iteration of the package looked nice and neat and rather simple. The problem came around when I wanted to write unit tests. Because of the way mocking works (or doesn't work) with implicit struct inheritance, I had to code my package differently, just so that the tests would work.

This is a small part of the redis extension package:

```golang
package cache

import (
    "time"

    "github.com/go-redis/redis"
    errors "github.com/pkg/errors"
)

// StringResult - Interface for implicit inheritence for redis.StatsCMD
type StringResult interface {
    Result() (string, error)
    Err() error
}

// Client - Interface that we use to wrap the redis lib around, so that we can mock it's behaivour
type Client interface {
    Ping() StringResult
    Get(string) StringResult
}

type redisclient struct {
    rc *redis.Client
}

func (c *redisclient) Ping() StringResult {
    return c.rc.Ping()
}

func (c *redisclient) Get(key string) StringResult {
    return c.rc.Get(key)
}

// NewCacheClient - Functiom to create a instance of RedisClient
var NewCacheClient = func(options *redis.Options) Client {
    // here wrap the *redis.Client into *redisclient
    return &redisclient{redis.NewClient(options)}
}

// Cache - Duplo Redis Type
type Cache struct {
    redis.Options
    DefaultLifetime time.Duration
    client          Client
}

// Connect - Connect to Reddis
func (cache *Cache) Connect() error {

    cache.client = NewCacheClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr:     cache.Addr,
        Password: cache.Password,
        DB:       cache.DB,
    })

    err := cache.checkConnection()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func (cache *Cache) checkConnection() error {
    _, err := cache.client.Ping().Result()
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "cache")
    }

    return nil
}

// Get - Get's a value from Redis. All values are returned as strings
func (cache *Cache) Get(key string) (bool, string, error) {

    var val string

    err := cache.checkConnection()
    if err != nil {
        return false, val, err
    }

    val, err = cache.client.Get(key).Result()
    if err == redis.Nil {
        // Key not found
        return false, val, nil
    }

    if err != nil {
        // Error happened
        return false, val, errors.Wrap(err, "cache")
    }

    // Value found
    return true, val, nil
}
```

Then this is my unit test for this bit of code:

```golang
package cache

import (
    "errors"
    "testing"

    "github.com/go-redis/redis"
    pkgErr "github.com/pkg/errors"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
)

/**
 * StringResult - Mock
 */
type StringResultMock struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (m *StringResultMock) Result() (string, error) {
    args := m.Called()
    return args.Get(0).(string), args.Error(1)
}

func (m *StringResultMock) Err() error {
    args := m.Called()
    return args.Error(0)
}

/**
 * RedisClient - Mock
 */
type redisClientMock struct {
    mock.Mock
}

func (m *redisClientMock) Ping() StringResult {
    args := m.Called()
    return args.Get(0).(StringResult)
}

func (m *redisClientMock) Get(key string) StringResult {
    args := m.Called(key)
    return args.Get(0).(StringResult)
}

func TestConnect(t *testing.T) {
    assert := assert.New(t)

    old := NewCacheClient
    defer func() { NewCacheClient = old }()

    tests := []struct {
        testName        string
        statusCmdResult string
        statusCmdErr    error
        expectedResult  error
    }{
        {"TestConnect-Success", "success", nil, nil},
        {"TestConnect-Fail", "failure", errors.New("error message"), pkgErr.Wrap(errors.New("error message"), "cache")},
    }

    for _, tc := range tests {
        t.Run(tc.testName, func(t *testing.T) {

            NewCacheClient = func(options *redis.Options) Client {
                assert.Equal("127.0.0.1:1001", options.Addr)
                assert.Equal("password", options.Password)
                assert.Equal(1, options.DB)

                statusCmdMock := new(StringResultMock)
                statusCmdMock.On("Result").Return(tc.statusCmdResult, tc.statusCmdErr)

                clientMock := new(redisClientMock)
                clientMock.On("Ping").Return(statusCmdMock)

                return clientMock
            }

            cache := Cache{}
            cache.Addr = "127.0.0.1:1001"
            cache.Password = "password"
            cache.DB = 1

            err := cache.Connect()
            if tc.expectedResult != nil {
                assert.Equal(tc.expectedResult.Error(), err.Error())
            } else {
                assert.Equal(nil, err)
            }
        })
    }
}

func TestGet(t *testing.T) {
    assert := assert.New(t)

    old := NewCacheClient
    defer func() { NewCacheClient = old }()

    baseError := errors.New("error message")
    wrappedError := pkgErr.Wrap(baseError, "cache")
    keyString := "key_string"
    keyValue := "key_value"

    tests := []struct {
        testName            string
        pingStatusCmdResult string
        pingError           error
        pingErrorWrap       error
        getKey              string
        getResultValue      string
        getResultErr        error
        getResultErrWrap    error
        expectedResult      bool
        expectedValue       string
    }{
        {"TestGet-CheckConnectFail", "failure", baseError, wrappedError, "", "", nil, nil, false, ""},
        {"TestGet-NoValue", "success", nil, nil, keyString, "", redis.Nil, nil, false, ""},
        {"TestGet-GetError", "success", nil, nil, keyString, "", baseError, wrappedError, false, ""},
        {"TestGet-Success", "success", nil, nil, keyString, "", nil, nil, true, keyValue},
    }

    for _, tc := range tests {
        t.Run(tc.testName, func(t *testing.T) {
            NewCacheClient = func(options *redis.Options) Client {
                assert.Equal("127.0.0.1:1001", options.Addr)
                assert.Equal("password", options.Password)
                assert.Equal(1, options.DB)

                pingStatusCmdMock := new(StringResultMock)
                if tc.pingError != nil {
                    pingStatusCmdMock.On("Result").Return(tc.pingStatusCmdResult, tc.pingError)
                } else {
                    pingStatusCmdMock.On("Result").Return(tc.pingStatusCmdResult, nil)
                }

                clientMock := new(redisClientMock)
                clientMock.On("Ping").Return(pingStatusCmdMock)

                if tc.pingError == nil {
                    getStatusCmdMock := new(StringResultMock)
                    getStatusCmdMock.On("Result").Return(tc.getResultValue, tc.getResultErr)

                    clientMock.On("Get", tc.getKey).Return(getStatusCmdMock)
                }

                return clientMock
            }

            cache := Cache{}
            cache.Addr = "127.0.0.1:1001"
            cache.Password = "password"
            cache.DB = 1

            connErr := cache.Connect()
            if tc.pingError != nil {
                assert.Equal(tc.pingErrorWrap.Error(), connErr.Error())
                return // If the connect fails, we don't get to the other code, so exit here
            }
            assert.Equal(nil, connErr)

            result, value, err := cache.Get("key_string")

            assert.Equal(tc.expectedResult, result)
            assert.Equal(tc.getResultValue, value)
            if tc.getResultErr == nil || tc.getResultErr == redis.Nil {
                assert.Equal(nil, err)
            } else {
                assert.Equal(tc.getResultErrWrap.Error(), err.Error())
            }
        })
    }
}
```

The package code structure is okay I guess, it could probably be better, but I think that will come in time as I work more with the language.

However, the test looks messy and ugly as hell. It seems to be a lot of code to test what is quite a simple function. There must be a better way to do this, or clean it up and make it simpler.

Is there something I'm missing? I feel like perhaps I'm coding the initial package incorrectly and maybe it's the reason I'm having to do a lot of extra work in the tests. Each test would probably look a bit cleaner if I wasn't doing table tests, but then we're looking at a lot of duplicate code for testing small differences in the function, so that's probably not the way to go.